# Combining selectors when one of the selectors is 'window'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I wanted to detect scroll events on a div with `class="foo"` or `id="bar"` i could use this syntax:

```
$('div.foo, div#bar').scroll(function(){ ... });
```

And if I want to detect window scroll I would do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ ... });
```

But how would I specify that I want to detect `scroll` events on the window OR on `div` elementss with `class="foo"`? I've tried this:

```
$(window, ".foo").scroll(function(){ ... });
```

It doesn't cause any errors but it only listens for `scroll` events on the `window`, suggesting that it's just ignored the second, unexpected, argument.

Comment: Well `window` is not something you can find with a selector.

Comment: why don't you just call scroll multiple times?

Comment: @DanielA.White i could but i'm trying to keep it neat, if possible.

Comment: @Pointy if i say `$(window)` am i not selecting the window?

Comment: No, you're not - you're instantiating a jQuery object around the `window` object. It's like getting a reference to a DOM node (like with `.getElementById()`) and then passing that to the jQuery function. You do get back a jQuery object that works as expected, but it performs no DOM search. A selector is a string.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean.  I was thinking of "selecting" as being the whole process of "getting the thing and making a jquery object out of it".  So, you could say that you're selecting the window but it's a special case that doesn't require a selector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the window cannot be directly selected using a string you could use `add()` to merge it with the two `div` elements. Try this:

```
$('div.foo, div#bar').add(window).scroll(function(){ 
    // ... 
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't know about `.add()`, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks - i'll mark this as correct as soon as it lets me.  :)